# List of Excel Workbook connections

Tags: microsoft-excel, r

I have many Excel files in folder. 
Is it possible to get list of connections? (maybe in R, python, ...)

*Example:*

file 1: connections: list
...

file n: connections: list

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "connections"?

Comment: I mean Links to other files.

Comment: Does [this page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-external-references-links-in-a-workbook-fcbf4576-3aab-4029-ba25-54313a532ff1) help? What have you tried?